# find database rows that start with a character using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I grab data from a database using an mySQL query which will get all rows that start with a certain string, for example;

```
$string = 'WS';

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` STARTS WITH '$string'");
```

something like the above

Comment: To follow the answer below, look into the % operator when using LIKE. It is a directional wildcard used exactly for this purpose. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 6):

you mean `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE 'WS%'
```

Comment: but that'll retrieve all results have **WS** in it's value, I only want the ones that have WS at the start

Comment: no, that will only retrieve where they begin with WS and have absolutely anything following WS

Comment: @Curtis That would only happen if you wrote `'%WS%'`.

Comment: consider also parameterizing the value to avoid sql injection. [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE 'WS%'
```

it will fetch only those values those have ws at the start...and not all values..try it once